# How to pass and modify $scope/context inside factory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple angular factory to access API and a number of different controllers. If the `$http.error()` is fired I want to pass error `data` to the controller, where the `appBackend` was fired (to display right error in the corresponding modal) and clear this error when the new call starts:

```
angularApp.factory('appBackend', function($http, APP_CONFIG, APP_ERROR_CODE) {
  // clear code, i.e. $scope.error = null;
  return function(model, method, data) {
    return $http.post(APP_CONFIG.API_PATH + '/' + model + '/' + method, data).error(function (data) {
      // pass code i.e. $scope.error = data;
  };
});
```

Gave a try to `apply()`, but received `appBackend(...).apply is not a function`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject the factory in the controller you are using.You can simple pass the **success** and **error**  from the `factory` or access the **success** and **error** in the `controller` itself like below.Binding the api call to a function will overwrite your previous `$scope` variable.

```
 angular.module('myApp', []).controller('checkController', function($scope, faceOfffactory) {

        var registerdata = {
            grant_type: 'password',
            UserName: $scope.signupData.username,
            Password: $scope.signupData.password,
            Phone: $scope.signupData.phone,
            Email: $scope.signupData.email,
        };

       $scope.signUp = function(){
        faceofffactory.signUp(registerdata).success(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                $scope.message = data.status;
                $state.go('.',null,{reload:true});//to reinitialize your controller.
            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log("http error", data);
                $scope.message = "failure";
            });
          }
        })
        .factory('faceofffactory', function($http, $sessionStorage, ) {

            var urlBase = 'http://apple.com:7071';
            var lastId;

            return {
                signUp: function(registerdata) {

                    return $http({
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: urlBase + '/api/Account/Register',
                        data: registerdata,
                    })
                }
            }
        })
```